# How to install netbeans-8.1 in ubuntu-15.10

Tags: 15.10, netbeans

I can't install netbeans-8.1 in my ubuntu-15.10 Desktop Computer.When I use  this command `#cd ~/Downloads && ./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh`

[image]

This scene comes but after that mouse doesn't work and when I click in the "Next" button,it doesn't work. What can I do now? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Have you already installed JDK?  It's required.  You can download a JDK/Netbeans bundle [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html).  The instructions [can be found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html#linux).

Answer (score 0):

Download NetBeans `.sh` file from [direct link](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=all) and open terminal and run:

```
chmod ugo+x netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```